# Pulumi Import GCP Instance Error in boot_disk property conflict

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, pulumi

Basically I've created a basic instance on GCP and used the pulumi import comand:

```
pulumi import gcp:compute/instance:Instance default <project>/<region>/<instance-name>
```

And this was the output:

```
gcp:compute:Instance (default):
error: gcp:compute/instance:Instance resource 'default' has a problem: Computed attribute cannot be set
error: gcp:compute/instance:Instance resource 'default' has a problem: ConflictsWith: "boot_disk.0.disk_encryption_key_raw": conflicts with boot_disk.0.kms_key_self_link
error: gcp:compute/instance:Instance resource 'default' has a problem: Computed attribute cannot be set
error: gcp:compute/instance:Instance resource 'default' has a problem: ConflictsWith: "boot_disk.0.kms_key_self_link": conflicts with boot_disk.0.disk_encryption_key_raw
error: Preview failed: one or more inputs failed to validate
```

Basically it says that those both attributes conflicts with each other, but I've didn't even set them on boot_disk property and because of that I cannot realize the import.

Comment: Hi, I'm also encountering the same issue. Have you been able to find a solution ?